# Regarding error in setup of github repository over jupyter notebook

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

```
Problem:->

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3369 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
```

How can we overcome this problem so that github code will run on my jupyter notebook?

Comment: Please provide us the full command, the full error, and what you have tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.